# I am not getting the print statement I want by using inputs for a shipping calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

- The Speedy Shipping Company will ship packages based on how much they weigh and how far they are being sent. They will only ship light packages up to 10 pounds. You have been tasked with writing a program that will help Speedy Shipping determine how much to charge per delivery.
- The charges are based on each segment of 500 miles shipped. Shipping charges are not pro-rated; i.e., 600 miles is the same charge as 900 miles; i.e., 600 miles is counted as 2 segments of 500 miles.

Your program should prompt the user for inputs (weight and miles), accept inputs from the keyboard, calculate the shipping charge, and produce accurate output.

Test:Prompts / Inputs:

```
Please enter package weight in pounds: 1.5
Please enter number of miles to ship: 200     (This is one 500-mile segment.)
Expected result:
To ship a 1.5 pound package 200 miles, your shipping charge is $1.50.
Helpful Hints:
You can use integer (floored) division. For example: 1200 // 500 =  2
```

So I have typed the code to the best of my knowledge however my `print` statement just prints (1.5). I need help in understanding why my `print` statement won't print the results.

```
# Package of Weight                  Rate per 500 miles shipped
# 2 pounds or less                   $1.50
# More than 2 but not more than 6    $3.75
# More than 6 but not more than 10   $5.25

weight_of_package = int(input("1.5"))

num_miles_ship = int(input("200"))

shipping_rate = 0

if weight_of_package > 0 and weight_of_package <= 2:
    shipping_rate = 1.50

elif weight_of_package > 2 and weight_of_package <= 6:
    shipping_rate = 3.75

elif weight_of_package > 6 and weight_of_package <= 10:
    shipping_rate = 5.25

else:
    print('Sorry, we only ship packages of 10 pounds or less')

shipping_charge = weight_of_package//num_miles_ship * shipping_rate

print(("To ship a " +str(weight_of_package) + "pound package" + str(num_miles_ship)
      + "your shipping charge is" + str(shipping_charge,".2f")))
```

Comment: You need to indent after your ```if```, ```elif```, and ```else``` statements.

Comment: The code in the question would give a syntax error - you need to fix the indents

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code has several indentation errors, at least one type error in the output formatting, and some logic errors.  You need to reduce this to a single question -- not a guess-and-edit session for us.

Comment: It is already indented in the IDE I am using I just forgot to indent it while posting the question.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.  So far, you haven't even checked your input processing for correctness.

Comment: Those aren't "`print` statements", they're `print()` _function_ calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1. The `input` method does probably do something else than you think. I does not convert anything, but it ask the user (you) for input and return this input. `a=input("enter value for a:")` will just open a prompt that will let you type something on your keyboard and when you press enter this will be copied into variable `a` here. So you may want to do `weight_of_package=int(input("enter weight of package: "))` etc.
2. In your if/elif sequence: careful! python uses indentation to understand your scoping! This is critical in python and wrong in your code. You have to intend code in the if/elif blocks.
3. You can save some typing in the `elif` statements, since all the `weight_of_package > XXX` statements have no effect because of the preceding if statements (this would be just the `else`)
4. Before you second-last line `shipping_charge = ...` you need to protect against `shipping_rate` equal to zero. This will happen for a `weight_of_package > 10` and will just fail in the calculation. Thus you need to add `if shipping_rate>0: ...`
5. Division operator in python is `/` not `//`
6. Best leave away the `,"2.f"` in `str(shipping_charge,".2f") since this does not do what you believe. If you do want to use formatted output use the standard python format syntax` "{:.2f}".format(shipping_charge)`. Please consult https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec which is very interesting and relevant.

Here is the full example:

```
# Package of Weight                  Rate per 500 miles shipped
# 2 pounds or less                   $1.50
# More than 2 but not more than 6    $3.75
# More than 6 but not more than 10   $5.25

weight_of_package = int(input("please enter weight of package: "))

num_miles_ship = int(input("please enter miles to ship: "))

shipping_rate = 0

if weight_of_package > 0 and weight_of_package <= 2:
    shipping_rate = 1.50

elif weight_of_package <= 6:
    shipping_rate = 3.75

elif weight_of_package <= 10:
    shipping_rate = 5.25

else:
    print('Sorry, we only ship packages of 10 pounds or less')

if shipping_rate > 0:
    shipping_charge = weight_of_package / num_miles_ship * shipping_rate

    print("To ship a {} pound package {} miles " 
          "your shipping charge is {:.2f} ".format(
          weight_of_package, num_miles_ship,  shipping_charge))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is probably not being executed at all right now

I am guessing that `1.5` which you are probably seeing is the result of this line probably

```
weight_of_package = int(input("1.5"))
```

The `input()` function in python takes an argument that tells the user about the input being required. So, if you change it to

```
weight_of_package = float(input("Enter the weight of package"))
```

and then run the program. You'll be prompted to `Enter the weight of package` following which you need to give the program input for the weight of the package ( and you'll enter `1.5` )

Also, you need to use `float` instead of `int` in that line as `1.5` is a decimal value

Making this change, it'll be easier for you to debug the `print` statements that are at the bottom of the code as `1.5` won't confuse you.

Comment: Also should keep in mind that they should cast to a float instead of an int if they are planning on setting the weight to 1.5

Comment: Right! didn't notice